# How to put multiple v-for and v-if statements in a table: Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a table, which has multiple v-if and v-for statements within it. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
        <table>
            <span v-for="(option, optionk) in bundle_item.build_options" v-bind:key="optionk">
                <span v-for="(obj, key) in bundle_item.bundle_subs_object" v-bind:key="'k' +key">
                    <span v-if="option == key">
                        <span v-for="(instance, instancek) in obj" v-bind:key="instancek">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{instance.name}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </table>
```

Is there a way to make this possible in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `template` tag. This tag will not be present in the produced dom.

```html
<table>
  <template v-for="(option, optionk) in bundle_item.build_options">
    <template v-for="(obj, key) in bundle_item.bundle_subs_object">
      <template v-if="option == key">
        <template v-for="(instance, instancek) in obj">
          <tr v-bind:key="`${optionk}${'k' +key}${instancek}`">
            <td>{{instance.name}}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </template>
    </template>
  </template>
</table>
```